# If WhatsApp cannot read our message, how can the media forwarding happen in an instant?

Tags: encryption, whatsapp

WhatsApp says even the photos shared on its platform are end-to-end encrypted. When WhatsApp says encrypted I assume the data is encrypted in my device and then sent across to the recipient.

When we are sending a photo for the first time we can see the actual upload happening (if you are in a slow network), but when we forward the same picture to someone else, the upload is not happening.
It happens in an instant.

AFAIK the photo would have been again encrypted with the key pair for the second recipient and then again sent to the second recipient. Since the second upload is not happening is it that the encryption happens in the WhatsApp server? Is WhatsApp decrypting the media file and encrypting it with the new recipient's key when we forward it?
Can it be called end-to-end encryption in that case?

Comment: May be because the media(photo, video) is already in your whatsapp memory, it only add encryption key and forward it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **security** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or perhaps  [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is possibly that the client simply forwards the content encryption key, encrypted with the public key of the new recipient, to the server which then forwards both to the new recipient. I have no idea what WhatsApp actually does.

Comment: In that case the second recipient will get the encryption key of first recipient, which is not expected.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't be expected. If data is encrypted once then every entity that is allowed to decrypt it must have the key. But I don't think this feature is part of the Signal protocol, if that's what you mean. WhatsApp must've bolted it on themselves. If true this fact should make one at least a little skeptical about its security. However, I still think it can be called end-to-end encryption because the server can't decrypt it, only the intended recipients.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not unique end to end encryption every time a message is shared. They probably store it like you said in an encrypted format and simply share that. This doesn't actually violate end to end encryption since from your device to the device you are sending to will be encrypted. This is just a guess though.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: But the new recipient doesn't have the key.

Comment: they can send the key too. Just because they aren't stored together doesn't mean they don't have access to the key too.